# Unicode character won't print using CairoPDF but will print using pdf device

Tags: r, pdf, grid, draw

CairoPDF is refusing to print a language object I have that contains a unicode character. It prints fine with the regular pdf device, though.

Using Cairo PDF results in a blank PDF:

```
library(Cairo)
num <- sprintf("%.2f", round(27.382, 2)) # Add a number
num <- gsub("\\.","\\\xB7", num) # Replace the decimal point in the number with a midline decimal point
my_text <- bquote(italic("I")^2 ~ " = " ~ .(num)) # Add some text before the number
CairoPDF("cairoTest", width = 10, height = 5) # Open device
grid.text(my_text, x=unit(.5, "npc"), y=unit(.5,"npc"), gp=gpar(fontfamily = "Helvetica", col = "black")) # Draw
dev.off() # Turn off device
```

If I replace the CairoPDF line with this in order to use the normal pdf device, it prints correctly:

```
pdf("pdfTest.pdf", width = 10, height = 5)
```

[pdf device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfkVZ.png)

Also, if I remove the line 'num <- gsub(".","\xB7", num)', it prints using CairoPDF.

[CairoPDF without unicode character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RX0K.png)

Notice the regular decimal point, however - I would like to replace the decimal point with a midline decimal.

**Does anyone know how I can print the midline decimal to pdf and continue to use CairoPDF?**

Thank you!

Comment: Pasting the mid dot, using the Octal code, using \xB7, and \u00b7 all do the same thing - they print fine with the pdf device, but CairoPDF shows nothing.

Comment: @K J Thanks for the links. Using cairo_pdf() does the same thing, unfortunately - nothing prints. Also, I can't use CairoFonts(); it comes up with a message that basically says I should just use the family argument, as I am.  
  
It might be important to note that the midline point prints fine using Cairo when it's on its own as the character 'num'. It's only when I add this line and create the language object 'my_text' that it refuses to print:  

my_text <- bquote(italic("I")^2 ~ " = " ~ .(num))